# Pro tools 10 crossfade shortcut

Tags: pro-tools-10, shortcut, fader

When I use this shortcut - Ctrl+Start+F (uses last selected fade shape) it actually always does the normal crossfade instead of the last used crossfade (the one with steep curves). Is that a bug or is it me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think ProTools ever uses the last used fade type.  There is a preference under "editing" to make and change the default fade type, I think thats what it always goes back to.